# I accidentally drank some water during bath, just about a drop on nirjala ekadashi

Tags: vaishnavism, ekadashi

Is my fast still valid? Like i asked in question that during taking bath, accidentally a small drop got in my mouth and i unknowingly drank water.

Comment: Feel like this stack has heartless people, i think by the time i get this answer, the ekadashi will be over

Comment: Sipping of water or drinking is done using hand with full intent and not through head .. in your case it is not so and it is purely accidental .. so the fast is valid IMO

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -2):

It depends. If the bath was before sunrise, one may say the vrata stands valid, otherwise, sipping water on the Nirjala Ekadashi day will void the vrata vow, if taken religiously.

> [Chapter 51](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365628.html) - Nirjalā Ekādaśī, Uttara Khanda, Padma Purana
>
> Vyāsa said:
>
> > - 19-26. **When the Ekādaśī would fall on (the day when the Sun) is in
> >   the second or the third sign of the Zodiac in the month of Jyeṣṭha, a
> >   wise man should carefully observe (the Ekādaśī fast) without (even
> >   drinking) water. He should avoid even sipping a mouthful of water and
> >   should not eat (at all). Otherwise the vow would be broken.**
> > - **Listen, when a man (lives even) by avoiding water from the sunrise
> >   of a day to the sunrise (of the next day), he obtains the fruit of
> >   twelve Dvādaśīs**. Then in the auspicious morning of the Dvādaśī day
> >   he should bathe, and having duly given water, gold etc. to brāhmaṇas,
> >   he, being contended and controlled, should eat along with brāhmaṇas.
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande

Further as per the Narada Purana also,

> [Narada Purana 1.4.120](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n159/mode/2up)
>
> ज्येष्ठस्य शुक्लैकादश्यां निर्जलां समुपोष्य तु ॥ १२०-१४ ॥
> उदयादुदयं यावद्भास्करस्य द्विजोत्तम ॥ प्रभाते कृतनित्यस्तु
> द्वादश्यामुपचारकैः ॥ १२०-१५ ॥ ह्यषीकेशं समभ्यर्च्य विप्रान् संभोज्य
> भक्तितः ॥ चतुर्विंशैकादशीनां फलं यत्तत्समाप्नुयात् ॥ १२०-१६ ॥
>
> > - 14b-16. On the eleventh day in the bright half of the month of Jyeștha, the holy rite of Nirjala (Abstention from water) Ekādaśī is
> >   observed. O excellent Brähmaņa, **from the sun-rise to sunrise (i. e.
> >   throughout the Ekadasi day) (not even water is to be taken in).** On the
> >   twelfth day in the morning, he performs the prescribed daily routine
> >   rites and worships Hrşikeśa with all the Upacaras; (thereafter) he
> >   feeds Brahminas with devotion. By performing this Ekadashi with proper
> >   rites, he reaps the benefit of doing 24 Ekadashis.
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande

### Conclusion:

Basis the above two excerpts from Padma Purana & Narada Purana, it is concluded that if the water sipping occurred before sunrise the fast remains valid, otherwise, it's not.

In the case of OP, as they say, that they accidentally sipped water, there might be a case of validity of the fasts, but I think, even Gandhari " accidentally" must-have "*fasted on the day of the tenth phase of the moon, and lost her hundred sons in consequence.*" (Garuda Purana [Ch. 75](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122605.html) - Brihaspati Samhita).

**Overall, I think the fast does not remain valid, since the very basic idea of the Nirjala-Ekadashi fasts is to remain without even a single drop of water throughout the day.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer